# IONIC 3: How to Set Background to Transparent in IOS with QR Scanner Plugin?

Tags: html, ios, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic Native plugin QR SCANNER but the app in IOS is not showing a preview. Did a lot of research but no solution works. I have set background-color: transparent !important to almost Everything including:

```
html, body, ion-app, ion-content, ion-page, .nav-decor, content-md, content-ios,ion-app.ios,.fixed-content,.scroll-content{
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

But still the app in IOS displays a white screen instead of a Preview And the QR scanner is working in the background just not showing the preview. everything works fine on Android.

Comment: You need to add the previewLayer to the current view. Don't know how in ionic..

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for replying but there is not any way to implement a Preview layer for this plugin in ionic.

Answer (score 1):

Finally Found the answer for ionic 3.
You can change the display property of the element **ion-app** to none every time you call the function to scan like this:

```
let ionApp = document.getElementsByTagName('ion-app')[0];
ionApp.style.display = 'none';
```

And when you get the text from the scanner, call:

```
ionApp.style.display = 'block';
```

And if you want you can use [Zbar Native plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/zbar/) instead of the QR-scanner-plugin.
Hope it is helpful to someone.